# how to change timestamp value for specific row or column in hbase from hbase shell

Tags: hbase

my requirement is to change the existing time stamp value for a specific row and column from H base shell.
so how can i change time stamp from H BASE shell?
what is difference between IN_MEMORY and CACHE MEMORY attributes at hbase table level

Answer (score 0):

Regrading the first part you can just re assign the value in the right place -

put ‘t1′, ‘r1′, ‘c1′, ‘value’, ts1

Comment: but the value is a huge xml file,so that i can't insert this xml file through shell. This XML file is programaticlly generated and stored in HBase.the above command is works fine if the value is possible to type in shell. thanks... Tom........

Answer (score 0):

After some research I believe @user2586498 is correct in the strictest sense. A particular instance of a row has a version (it doesn't have to be a timestamp). Once that row is persisted it is locked it. You can overwrite that value but it must be with a different version.

An alternative solution is to persist your own version number in a separate column.

Another alternative solution is to not store large XML docs in a hbase. Rather store them in some sort of file store or CDN and only store the paths/references in HBase.